# How to run a command using ref ID in ArcGIS Pro SDK

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-pro-sdk

I am new to pro SDK. I am trying to add a button to a menu which will do the identical function to the copy coordinates command:

[image]

and then I would run further code when I get those coordinates in the clipboard.

I would assume the code for the button function would look something similar to this:

```
internal class MyButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        protected internal virtual Func<Task> ExecuteCommand(string id = "esri_mapping_copyCoordinates");
        //other code goes here
    }
}
```

This is based on the reference guide: [ArcGIS Pro Reference - ExecuteCommand Method](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/sdk/api-reference/topic10514.html)

However, this does not seem to compile.

Can anyone help me out with this? Basically, I'm just looking for a code sample on how to run an existing ArcGIS Pro command.

Comment: Just an idea have you explored [code snippets](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/ProSnippets)?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [page](https://github.com/esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/ProGuide-Reusing-Pro-Commands) in the documentation, which shows several different ways of re-using existing ArcGIS Pro Commands:

- Reusing ArcGIS Pro Commands in your Add-in Ribbon UI by Reference
- Reusing ArcGIS Pro Commands in your Add-in Ribbon UI in Code-Behind
- Reusing ArcGIS Pro Commands in MVVM
- Reusing ArcGIS Pro Commands in MVVM Code-Behind

Comment: Thank you so so much!!! That was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Please remember to click the check mark to signify your question was answered. This will help others searching for the same solution.